# Extract value from sql result

Tags: mysql

1. On our website, our user can save a note through a text area
2. It is saved in the database in table notes
3. Table notes have Columns: ID, UserID, Notes
4. The input of user is saved in column Notes along with the date in html format for example:

```
<b><u><span style="font-size: 8pt">15-03-16 00:26&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>Pgrahame</u></b>&nbsp;&nbsp;<br />note of the user<br><br />
```

5. Now we want to extract the date (the one inside span tag) for each of the saved notes for saving to a new separate column of dates
6. Already tried using ExtractValue() function of mysql, apparently it only works for proper xml formatted texts unlike this one.

Comment: what did you try so far? what language do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes you don't need to make such one-time jobs harder than it is. Just query the data with a substring-function. Something like:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(Notes.Notes, 36,14) as DatetimePart
FROM Notes
```

This will only work when the syntax of the html is always the same!

Comment: Yes, thank you. The syntax is the same through out the db.